# Trouble with arithmetic operators in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

```
$scope.showTotal = function() {
    $scope.pT = [];
    var iT = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.od.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.od[i]['bpr']);
        iT += $scope.od[i]['bpr'];
        // also tried this -> iT = iT + $scope.od[i]['bpr']
    }
    $scope.pT.push({iTotal: iT});
    console.log($scope.popupTotals);
    $scope.showPopupNow = true;
}
```

But I don't know why it's not working. 
If the bpr is for example 50 and 43.1034, then it logs the output in console something like this, `iTotal:"050.000043.1034"`

I am new to JavaScript and I started it directly with AngularJS. 
So please help me with arithmetic operators in JS.
Thank You.

Comment: Why you duplicate i++ at end?

Comment: removed it. @AlexanderAnikeev

Comment: What type do you have in the object $scope.order[i]['baseprice'] ? If it string, you must to parseFloat.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderAnikeev  for your help. It's working.

Comment: You are welcome! You have many correct answers at bottom. Check one of its!

Comment: Yes. I'm waiting for the accept button to be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.showTotal = function() {
    $scope.popupTotals = [];
    var itemtotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.order[i]['baseprice']);
        itemtotal += parseFloat($scope.order[i]['baseprice']);
        // parseFloat will convert string to number and add the number instead of concatenating the strings
    }
    $scope.popupTotals.push({itembasetotal : itemtotal});
    console.log($scope.popupTotals);
    $scope.showPopupNow = true;
}
```

Comment: @RahulJain - Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing i inside the loop .Remove the duplicate i and I suspect that your `$scope.order[i]['baseprice']` is not an integer. So convert it to an integer using `parseFloat`

```
$scope.showTotal = function(){
        $scope.popupTotals = [];
        var itemtotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i<$scope.order.length; i++){
            console.log($scope.order[i]['baseprice']);
            itemtotal += parseFloat($scope.order[i]['baseprice']);
            //also tried this -> itemtotal = itemtotal + $scope.order[i]['baseprice']
            //i++; No need to increment here
        }
        $scope.popupTotals.push({itembasetotal : itemtotal});
        console.log($scope.popupTotals);
        $scope.showPopupNow = true;
    }
```

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Is your $scope.order[i]['baseprice'] a string?. Try updated answer using parseFloat